# Confusion Matrix not displaying "TRUE" column?

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I have a dataset with 12000 entries. I want to compute confusion matrix but it is not displaying "TRUE" column. Here is my code:

```
conmat <- table(Actual_value = train$PregOutcome, Predicted_value = res>0.5)
conmat
```

this is the resulting matrix with missing "TRUE" column

```
        Predicted_value
Actual_value FALSE
       0     1546
       1     8184
```

I want my resulting confusion matrix like this?

```
  Predicted_value
Actual_value  FALSE   TRUE
     0        1546    XYZ
     1        8184    XYZ
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have `TRUE` in your `Predicted_value` column? Are there maybe missing values? You can check this with adding `useNA = "ifany"` to your table.

Comment: What does `summary(res)` say?